# How do you get the "user_id" of the token payload into the JSON POST form?Django REST, simpleJWT, Vue3

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

So i have access and refresh tokens in my local storage. The decoded access token has `"user_id"` in the payload. I have a problem understanding how do you make a POST request to the REST API, where the JSON form includes the `"user_id"` of the currently logged in user. Do i get it from the stored JWT or is there another way?

For a valid POST request i need 3 fields:

```
{
"post_author": "field, which needs the currently logged in user, aka user_id from the token "
"post_body": "some text"
"post_title": "some text"
}
```

Simplified question, how do you get the `"user_id"` of the decoded token into the JSON form?

**createPost.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="authenticationDiv">
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="postTitle" placeholder="post_title" />
      <input type="text" v-model="postBody" placeholder="post_body" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <button @click="createPost">Submit Post</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {  getPosts } from "./importable_functions";
import { ref } from "vue"

export default {
  setup() {
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";
    
    const postTitle = ref("");
    const postBody = ref("");

    async function createPost() {
      // var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create_post/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          // "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          post_body: postBody.value,
          post_title: postTitle.value,
          // post_author: 
        }),
      }).then((response) => {
        getPosts();
        return response;
      });
    }
    
    return {
      postTitle,
      postBody,
      createPost,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**views.py** create_post view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_post(request):
    serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(post_author=request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_author_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="post_author.username")
    post_author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="post_author")

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py** - post and customUser models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_body = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    fav_color = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=120)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `post_title` and `post_body` in the JSON and add user id during save:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_post(request):
    serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(post_author=request.user) # add post author
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Please remember to update serializer, I think it will be good to set `post_author` as read-only field.

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_author_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="post_author.username")

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        read_only_fields = (post_author_username, post_author)
        fields = (post_author_username, post_author, post_title, post_body)
```

Comment: Ook, did that, but im having a problem with changing the serializer. What source do i need to put, if i reference is the same field?Pointing the source to the same name creates an error, saying that i need to remove the source keyword argument. included the updated code and other snippets in the post

Comment: Please update your serializer by setting `read_only_fields`. I updated the answer.

Comment: copied the answer,  got an error, which says that the values defined in the `read_only_fields` parentheses are not defined.

Comment: Fixed, changed  the tuples to arrays . Now, once i send the body and the title from vue, i get a 500 response with an `Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000011D5127CB20>": "Post.post_author" must be a "CustomUser" instance.` error. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: You don't have a logged-in user. You need to log in as a user. And then create the post. I can recommend my tutorial about Django+React https://saasitive.com/tutorial/django-react-boilerplate-saas/  you will get there auth + CRUD with explanations.